# Customizing the code formatting style in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I use Eclipse IDE to format my code, i.e `ctrl+shift+f`

Here is what it's doing:

```
int[] array = 
        { 1, 2, 7, 1 };
```

Here is what I wish it did:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 7, 1 };
```

How can I stop the Eclipse formatter from putting a new line after equals when initalizing array ?

Comment: Ah I've had this with System.out.println() where the .println() will be on a new line after auto format. +1

Answer (score 2):

Hope this http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse can help you, take a look

Try steps below in your eclipse:

- Window Menu -> Preferences;
- Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit your active profile;
- Go to Line Wrapping Tab;
- Search for "Expressions -> Array Initializers;
- Change Settings for array initializers, Line wrapping policy: "Do not wrap".
  OR
- Go to "Braces" Tab;
- Check if array initializer option is "Same Line".

Comment: Please add some extra information, link are unreliable.

Comment: @CMPSoares - He will have to copy paste the whole link for that. Not sure if SO will consider that as plagiarism.

Comment: @james Nobody is saying to perform plagiarism, what I mean is that the content might be great but what SO suggests is that you at least explain it, even if you only make summary and keep the link as reference. This because if the link dies the answer will become worthless.

Comment: @johnnykp that's what I mean. +1 from me! ;-)

Comment: @user2884789 check "Braces" tab in your Active profile and view if array initializer option is "Same Line"

Comment: @johnnykp that worked! Maybe edit your answer above in case anyone else needs it.